# Determine Fourier Series for $f(\theta) = e^{r\cos(\theta)}\cos(r\sin(\theta))$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The book's suggestion is that $f(\theta) = Re(e^z)$ and it tells to expand $e^z$ using taylor series and show $f(\theta) = Re(e^z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{r^n}{n!}\cos(n\theta)$

but is it correct to assume $f(\theta) = Re(e^z)$

Comment: Why do you think it is not right? Try working backwards, writing $z=re^{i\theta}$ and take the real part of $e^z$

Comment: Because the question is determine fourier series for $f(\theta) = e^{r\cos(\theta)}\cos(r\sin(\theta))$ and not  $ f(\theta) = e^{r\cos(\theta)}$ .

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense? It would be even less sensible to think of using complex without the cos part.

Comment: I know $e^z = e^{r(cos(\theta) + isen(\theta))} $ and $Re(e^z) = e^{rcos(\theta)}$. It is easy to show the fourier of this series. But what happens with that part $cos(rsin(\theta))$ ?

Comment: Oh perfect you're on the right track then! Just substitute $z=re^{i\theta}$ into the Taylor series then take the real part

Comment: The real part of Taylor series for $e^{r(cos(\theta) + isin(\theta))} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{r^n}{n!}\cos(n\theta)$.

Comment: I GOT IT. NOW I GOT IT! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!